# Can we use <figcaption> on images without using <figure>

Tags: html

This is obviously a very different question to: "Can a `<figure>` element contain only a `<figcaption>` without an image?"

I am converting my website to use HTML5 semantic elements. I have lots of portfolio pages, containing lots of images. Each image has a caption, like this:

```
 <img ... >
 <p class="caption">... </p>
```

Can I replace the `p` tag and class with `figcaption` without having to wrap the image and the caption in a `figure` element?

Wrapping all the images and captions in a `figure` element will be a pain for me to do, and adds extra (unnecassary) code.

Using `figcaption` seems like semantically better than using a `p` tag with a class.

The images are not directly referenced by the main text on the page, so using `figure` isn't strictly necassary or needed (and as I've said I'm loath to spend the time doing this and feel it adds to code bloat).

Comment: Some-what decent text editors these days have RegEx find-and-replace functionality. With RegEx and a 'replace all' it is definitely possible *and* easy to change your code to valid HTML, including a `figure`-tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but it wouldn't be valid HTML. The [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-figcaption-element) say the parent must be a `<figure>`:

> Permitted parent elements:    A `<figure>` element; the `<figcaption>`
>   element must be its first or last child.

Comment: It seems a shame that I will have to stick with the less semantic p tag and class – but alas that is what I will do

Comment: @Markeee: An orphaned figcaption isn't any better. There is no way for the browser or other user agent consuming the HTML to associate the figcaption with the image if there is no figure containing both elements.

Comment: @j08691 I would like to use the <picture> tag and add a label. Is that possible?